# Android Studio: assuring apps and virtual devices compatibility

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, version, compatibility

I tried running some simple programs on some virtual androids that use API level 19, but seems like none of them are compatible, i.e.:[image]

Here are the module properties: [image]

My min SDK version:

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

My questions:

1. How to assure virtual devices and apps compatibility ahead of time (a checklist of conditions that need to be fullfilled in order for them to be compatible).
2. How does the IDE check for compatibility? What kinds of things does it compare? Min SDK required, API level?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Android Studio but before for Eclipse you the IDE detect the API version from AndroidManifest.XML ; Look for something similar here.
For the Apps - AVDs comparability when you create or use an AVD you already specifying the API and same you do for the Application once creation.

Comment: I added the min SDK version from the manifest file. Did not see that it was not displayed since I posted the question.

Comment: I added the min SDK version from the manifest file. Did not see that it was not displayed since I posted the question.

@Sadiq I understand that a mapping between the api levels in the virtual device and app. Just wanted to find yout whether this is the  only criteria and (if it is) maybe even why  is the app not compatible  with the device in my specific case.

Comment: Other criteria shouldn't be your concern because Android features flexibility for many factors such as screen size, the rest of hardware aspects shouldn't be an issue like CPU or RAM; are you creating heavy game or resource-consuming application where if it wasn't sufficient it wouldn't run ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you migrating the apps from Eclipse to Android Studio ?

Comment: No. They are originally created in Android studio.